Extract interfaces defined within `declare global`
A library I use has defined an internal set of interfaces like so:
declare global {
    export interface Foo { ... }
    export interface Bar { ... }
}

While the intent is that these aren't meant to be used externally, they're quite useful for my needs and I do need to consume them. I don't control the library, so I cannot change it, and it is altered often enough that patching or vendoring are not viable either.
Is there any way to access the types by name? I cannot rely on them as globals, so import 'my-lib/src/global.d.ts' is out of the question too. Something like myLib.Foo, IFoo, etc.
I understand this might not be possible, as it's going against author intent pretty clearly, just wanted to check before I have to resort to // @ts-ignore comments everywhere.

Why can't you "rely on them as globals"?

I have conflicting local types not only for Foo & Bar, but also 5-6+ other interfaces that are defined in that module. It's also really unclear & error prone to rely on the global types to be the unprefixed/unsignaled types, with my local types having to take on prefixes. Very easy to accidentally use the wrong types. Not viable, unfortunately.

Your local types aren't in modules? Why would you need to use prefixes for your local types? You can access global types like globalThis.Foo and keep your own types named whatever you want, as shown in this playground link. Anyway, please [edit] to indicate why you can't just use the types as globals, since comments can be deleted whenever without history.

They're not in modules, no. I similarly use global declarations myself. globalThis.Foo still pollutes the local scope with all sorts of types I don't want, so I don't think it's viable either, though certainly could be in other situations. Why I can't use types as globals isn't relevant; the post said I cannot and that's sufficient enough to answer the question (if possible).

"Why I can't use types as globals isn't relevant" I'm not sure why you'd say it's not relevant, because it's the natural suggestion. If you said "I want to trim spaces from the ends of a string but I cannot use the trim() method of a string", the reason certainly is going to be relevant to anyone who reads that question. But it's up to you, I guess. Anyway if the types are added in the library via global augmentation then they're global, so there's nothing you can do with tsc directly (maybe a codegen build step to extract the definitions? but that's probably out of scope)
